# Infinite source rectangle to drawImage method

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Why do i always get this log, `Infinite source rectangle to drawImage method`, is this such an error or there's something wrong with the code algorithm. I don't really understand about this, and i can't find any useful information on google. Hope i can find the answer on this site.

sorry, this is my drawRect method :

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect {
    // Drawing code here.

    // drawBackground
    [[NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1.0] set];
    [NSBezierPath fillRect:[self bounds]];

    if (myCIImage != nil) {

        //Create the CIContext
        CIContext *context =  [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] CIContext];

        //scale to fit in view rect
        CIImage *drawnImage;
        if (previewFilter == YES) {
            drawnImage = [previewImage imageByApplyingTransform:[self imageTransformToFitView]];
        } else {
            drawnImage = [myCIImage imageByApplyingTransform:[self imageTransformToFitView]];
        }

        // center in view rect
        NSRect viewBounds = [self bounds];
        CGRect sRect = [drawnImage extent];
        CGRect dRect = sRect;
        dRect.origin.x = viewBounds.origin.x + (viewBounds.size.width - sRect.size.width)/2;
        dRect.origin.y = viewBounds.origin.y + (viewBounds.size.height - sRect.size.height)/2;


        [context drawImage:drawnImage
                    inRect:dRect
                  fromRect:sRect];

    }

}
```

thanks -

Comment: Help, I wrote this code but it gives wrong result. Honestly, how could anyone help you without seeing the code?

Comment: well, i don't really know which part of my code that resulting this log. I was modified my app to support with the MotionBlur filter. The other filter is works very well but this one. I bind the inputRadius value and inputAngle value with the horizontal sliders, this is the same method as i used for another filter.

Comment: If you get a log message that says you passed an infinite source rectangle to the `drawImage:::` method, it's probably because you passed an infinite source rectangle to the `drawImage:::` method. The next step is to find out why your source rectangle is infinite. Read your code: What have you written that affects the source rectangle?

Comment: have you solved this?

Answer (score 1):

I think that means the dimensions of sRect contain some infinite numbers.  Have you run this under the debugger and inspected the values in sRect?

Probably the transform you apply to the image is wrong.